# Remove Scroll EventListener After Firing Once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, removeeventlistener

In my React project, I have a scroll event listener that checks when the user scrolls passed 590, setting state to true. This seems to work fine however I only want the function associated with the to run once so I'm adding `removeEventListener` as seen below, however the event continues to fire.

How do I appropriately remove this event listener?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleNavSlide = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 590) {
        setIsOpen(String(true))

        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsOpen(String(false))
        }, 2000)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleNavSlide)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleNavSlide)
  }, [])
```

Comment: So call the removeEventListener in the if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen because as per your **dependency array** which is `[]` here, your listener will only get removed when the component unmounts. For the **once** behaviour, change your implementation like so :-

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleNavSlide = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 590) {
        setIsOpen(String(true))

        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsOpen(String(false))
        }, 2000)
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleNavSlide)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleNavSlide)
  }, [])
```